# Can layer 2 or higher on Bitcoin handle billions of transactions and records to enable a form of decentralised democracy?

Tags: blockchain, voting

Essentially I'm asking if layer 2 or higher can handle billions of transactions and records as I'd like to develop / encourage the development of an app that can essentally hold all voter records (for at least one nation but eventually all).

Due to security concerns on the standard Internet we have to rely on tradional voting methods which are coming more and more under manipulation. My proposed app would benefit from the security of the Bitcoin network making it unhackable while providing easier ability for people to vote and enhance rapid delivery of voting results. This would also help reduce / eliminate corruption and manipulation of voting results.

This would take democracy forward into the 21st century. It can also be enhanced further to allow voting on other significant matters by the general public helping give more power back to the people. In time hopefully changes can be made in governments to allow the people to take more action / make decisions in their local area too leading to a fully decentralised democracy.

If there are any developers who can or are interested in developing this. Feel free to reach out on Twitter / X so we can have a conversation around this.

Kind regards
Wesley Kellingray

Comment: Blockchains themselves barely help with voting (see https://benlog.com/2017/12/28/blockchain-and-voting/). Layer 2 is all about even avoiding having to publish the transaction *at all*, which seems even less applicable to voting. I'd encourage you to look into the research that has been done to improve voting systems with cryptography; they can get a whole lot further than what's possible using blockchains - a technology that was designed for monetary transactions.